# Conexão com dois bancos em c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, oracle

Preciso realizar conexão com dois tipos de banco de dados, sendo eles: Oracle e Postegre.
Preciso ir no Oracle, gerar um spool com algumas consultas e subir esse spool no Postegre.
É possível realizar isso em C#?
Estou tendo muita dificuldade em encontrar conteúdo referente a este tema em fórum etc..
Posso este código para conexão ORACLE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace aplicacao_fatura_devolvida
{
    class ConsultaBancoOra
    {
        //public Process Sqlpl { get; private set; }
        private string connection = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" +
            "(HOST=xx.xx.xx.xxx)(PORT=xxxx))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xx))); User Id=xxxx; Password=xxxxxx";
        //Consulta ORACLE
        [Obsolete]
        public ConsultaBancoOra()
        {
            //String de Conexão
            OracleConnection ora = new OracleConnection(connection);
            //OracleCommand oraComand = new OracleCommand();
            //oraComand = ora.CreateCommand();
            //oraComand.CommandText = " select * from tb_003_ref_fd_dados_carga_base;";
            //oraComand.CommandTimeout = 15;
            //oraComand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Conexão realizada");
        }
        [Obsolete]
        public void AbrirConexaoOra()
        {
            OracleConnection ora = new OracleConnection(connection);
            ora.Open();
        }
        [Obsolete]
        public void FechaConexaoOra()
        {
            OracleConnection ora = new OracleConnection(connection);
            ora.Close();
        }
        public void ExecuteScriptOra(string Script, bool sequencial)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Sqlplus", $@" -d "" host=xx.xx.xx.xxxx port=xxxxdbname=xxxxx user=xxxxpassword=xxxxx"" " + Script);
                    //process.StandardInput.WriteLine();
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.Start();
                    if (sequencial)
                    {
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim, é possível. Faça a consulta normalmente no Oracle e "igualmente normalmente" faça o insert no Postgres. Não há o que misturar os temas. Entretanto, possivelmente não faria isso com SQL, mas além de não ser conhecido o seu use case, estaria fora do escopo da pergunta. Caso o objetivo seja sincronizar os 2, pode experimentar ferramentas como o debezium.io.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Na verdade, preciso criar em C# um botão no forms, este botão irá gerar um spool com as tabelas que irei mencionar e o postegre irá pegar esses arquivos spool e subir o arquivo atualizado. Não estou conseguindo sair deste entrave, consegui conectar com postegre, mas com oracle não..

Comment: crie duas connections, uma com Oracle e outra com Postgree, isso é simples e tem muitos exemplos, depois faça a consulta usando a connection do Oracle e o que precisar com os dados na outra connection. Coloque na pergunta o que já tem de código e onde estão as duvidas

Comment: Opa, Ricardo. Tudo bem?
Consegui conexão com o Postegre, porém com Oracle estou com dificuldades, mas estou vendo exemplos e alguns vídeos..

Comment: @RicardoPontual anexei minha conexão oracle na publicação para melhor entendimento

Comment: tem muita coisa estranha ai, por exemplo método `FechaConexaoOra` pra que abrir para fechar em seguida? evite isso, no método onde cosulta, abra a conexão dentro de um bloco `using (var conexao = new OracleConnection(connection))`. Mas qual o erro? coloque isso num try/catch para ver qual o problema. Lembre que dependendo da conexão, o Oracle precisa que o nome esteja naquela file tnsnames.ora se não me engano. Olhe aqui uns exemplos de strings: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/connection-strings-for-oracle/

Comment: Obrigado, @RicardoPontual. 
Irei analisar e olhar este site que me enviou, obrigado..